# How to make the host use the production build folder of the app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, build, create-react-app

I am trying to deploy my app to AWS elastic beanstalk. What i want to achieve is that i want all my api routes to get served from build folder for that i have written the config like this:

```
process.env.DEV_PROXY
  ? app.use("/", devProxy)
  : app.use("*", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build")));
```

My env file:

```
PORT=8080
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "phyxable",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "antd": "^4.7.0",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "firebase": "^7.20.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-calendar": "^3.1.0",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-jw-player": "^1.19.1",
    "react-markdown": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "react-transition-group": "4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "node-env-run server --exec nodemon | pino-colada",
    "server:prod": "node server",
    "dev": "run-p server start"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.3.3"
  }
}
```

But for some reason when it gets deployed it always use the development build. what might be the reason behind it not using the build folder.

Comment: maybe in your build command you can prepend the following: `DEV_PROXY=production yarn run build`

Comment: You aren't checking the value of the `DEV_PROXY` in your condition statement. Check the value of it for development or production and then change the ENV value to production when you deploy

Comment: So like `"build": "react-scripts build DEV_PROXY=production yarn run build"` this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my Heroku environment. I noticed the env variable was not returning correct value.

If I was in your place I would try to **console.log(process.env.DEV_PROXY)**. My guess is the value is not coming right in the AWS.

Comment: okk i tried to even remove the condition by only keeping `app.use("*", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build"))); in my server but it still didn't make any change.
`